# Programmatically install Android app from java program (Runtime.getRunTime().exec(adb.exe install app_package_name)

Tags: java, android

I am writing a automation program where from Java code, Android app has to be installed and later uninstalled.

The sample snippet is:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRunTime().exec(adb.exe install -s device_id apks\app_package_name);
```

I used right values for above app_package_name, does not have `.apk` file extension and `device_id` respectively.

This does not install the app on device. The app is user app.

Can you please let me know if I have to make any settings in app (in manifest file) or elsewhere (or in Java program) to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use adb when you perform it programatically,

Specifying the apk path in your machine and the package name will by default push the app to the device and will land in the launcher activity/home screen ogf your app, try using the below code,

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class installApp{
     static AndroidDriver<WebElement>  driver;

    private static DesiredCapabilities capa = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException  {
    capa = new DesiredCapabilities();    
    capa.setCapability("automationName","Appium"); 
    capa.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    capa.setCapability("deviceName","device name");
    capa.setCapability("udid", "ur device udid");  
    capa.setCapability("platformVersion","5.1");
    capa.setCapability("newCommandTimeout","30");
    capa.setCapability("appPackage", "com.your app's package name"); 
    capa.setCapability("appActivity", "com.your app's launcher activity");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capa);


}
}
```